# Help with polynomial problem: Factor the following expression $x^4-16y^2+20x^2+25$

Tags: polynomials

> Factor  the following  expression 
>   $$x^4-16y^2+20x^2+25$$

I try many times , couldn't solve it

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that it is $20x^2$ and not $10x^2$?

Comment: The expression isn't factorable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $x^4 + 10x^2+25 = (x^2+5)^2, 16y^2 = (4y)^2$. Did you check your problem for error? there seems to be one with the $20$. Should it be $10$ instead?